# CMU Sphinx for Indian English

Tags: cmusphinx

I have tried CMU Sphinx and it works fine with American English. Now,I want to use CMU Sphinx for detecting (Indian Accent) English. What exactly are the steps/changes I should do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you will have to do is adapt the acoustic model. Check the CMU Sphinx wiki page, they have explained the procedure of both training and adapting acoustic models. The link that works for now: http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/

According to what the site says,

> CMUSphinx provides ways for adaptation which is sufficient for most cases when more accuracy is required. Adaptation is known to work well when you are using different recording environments (close-distance or far microphone or telephone channel), or when a slightly different accent is present (UK English or even Indian English) or even another language.

Comment: Is adapting acoustic model alone enough? Does following things in this link (http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialam)sufficient?

Comment: I haven't done the process, but i'd recommend you go through both the one u posted and (http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialadapt), and see which suits you best. If you have problems with implementing what those pages say, then ask questions. When the questions are more specific, you'd get better answers. As for your problem, i believe adapting will wok (the link i am posting in this comment).

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can also do is download pre-trained files from here:

https://sourceforge.net/projects/cmusphinx/files/Acoustic%20and%20Language%20Models/

The files inside these .tar.gz are a bit different from the structure I have in my version of the lib, so I had to follow the steps in the following link to make it work:

https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition/issues/192

I'll show the steps I have taken, which are basically what the link above says, but it may die, so here it goes:

On my computer (Ubuntu 18.04.4), the dictionaries are kept here:

```
~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/speech_recognition/pocketsphinx-data
```

Inside the above folter, I had a subfolder en-US, in which I have the following files (F) and directories (D):

```
D acoustic-model
F language-model.lm.bin
F LICENSE.txt
F pronounciation-dictionary.dict
```

So I downloaded the .tar.gz for Indian language and made it look like the en-US directory. Like this:

```
tar zxvf cmusphinx-en-in-8khz-5.2.tar.gz
mv cmusphinx-en-in-8khz-5.2 en-IN
cd en-IN
mv en-us.lm.bin language-model.lm.bin
mv en_in.dic pronounciation-dictionary.dict
mv en_in.cd_cont_5000 acoustic-model
cd ..
```

Then I moved it to the correct directory.

```
mv en-IN ~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/speech_recognition/pocketsphinx-data
```

From this point, I was able to use en-IN.